# Single Sign-On using Asp.net MVC 4 and Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth, single-sign-on, owin

We are devloping application looks like Google login. for example if you login Gmail and open Play Store in  another tab it will automatically login playstore.

we want to develop similar application using ASP.Net MVC 4 and WEB API & JQuery.

1. User Flow (Login using username and password) - after login access member details
2. Client Flow (Client Secret and Client Id) - Authenticate HTML, Javascrip and CSS

If you have any suggestions on below approach.
1. OAuth 2.0 and Owin Middleware
2. Token base approach
3. to get HTML and Javascript using token by site.
4. cross domain token handling

if you have any sample for Resource server, here resource server is HTML, Javascript and CSS

Answer (score 0):

For the User Flow, you can use OpenIdConnect Middleware: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet. There are many additional samples in AzureADSamples.

Fore the Client Flow, this sample give a good example: https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-WebAPI-OAuth2-AppIdentity-DotNet.